# Memory alignment in an array of structures

Tags: c, arrays, memory, alignment, structure

I have an array of structures defined as below:

`struct {
    int x;
    char y;
} arr[10];`

The size of int on my machine is 4 bytes and a char is of 1 byte. I know the structures would be padded internally i.e each element of array will have a size of 8 bytes. But i want to know  whether

1) This is because of the alignment requirement of the int-type member in the next array element or

2) Is it because each structure should itself be aligned on a 8-byte boundary because of the requirement of natural alignment on a structure type variable.

To make my point more clear what should be starting address of the first member of array?
If it's an 8 byte aligned address as pointed out in the second case, this may be a problem while defining large 2-D arrays like:

int arr[1000][1000];

Here each element of the 2-D array (i.e each 1-D array) should be aligned on a 4000 byte boundary. The machine may not have memory hole to fulfill this memory requirement.

Comment: Which programming language?

Comment: Its C. Also if I apply sizeof on a single instance of the struct (not an element of the struct array) defined separately, I get 8 bytes as an answer and not 5 bytes. Why is it so? Does the compiler pad even in the case of a single instance, when the memory is free after the memory occupied by the instance?

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure I understand the difference between the two options you mention.

Every type in C++ has a natural alignment, of which its size is a multiple. But the alignment is not necessarily equal to the size of the object.

For example, an int typically has a natural alignment of 4 bytes, and a size of 4 bytes.

But while an array of 1000 ints has a size of 4000 bytes, it still only requires a 4-byte alignment.

Compound types (structs and arrays) only require the same alignment as their most-aligned *member*. An array of 1000 ints only contains objects of one type: int. And that type requires 4-byte alignment, so the array as a whole also only requires 4-byte alignment.

Likewise for your example struct, it has a size of (usually) 8 bytes, but it consists of an int (which requires 4 byte alignment), and a char (which requires 1-byte alignment). The strictest alignment required by any of its members is therefore 4 - and so the struct requires 4-byte alignment

Comment: Thanks a lot! Was a little confused about the concept. Also if I apply sizeof on a single instance of the struct(not an element of the struct array) defined separately, I get 8 bytes as an answer and not 5 bytes. Why is it so?

Comment: Yeah, that's because of another rule that there can be no padding between elements in an array. So say you create an array of your structs. Each of the elements has to be aligned on an 8-byte boundary, but if the size was 5, then the second element would be placed at a 5-byte boundary instead. So to ensure that every element is placed on an 8-byte boundary, the size is required to be a multiple of the alignment requirement.